# Reading variable in for loop inside a function in bash

Tags: function, for-loop, parallel-processing

Let's say I have this function

```
myfunc() {
  parallelinput="$1"
  #strip prefix
  filenames1=( "${parallelinput##*/}" )
echo /home/"$i"/"$filenames1"_count.tsv
echo "$1"
}

export -f myfunc
```

#I want to run parallel

```
STEPS=( 13 "13.5" )
for i in  "${STEPS[@]}"
do
parallel -j 2 myfunc  {}  ::: /home/$i/*vcf
done
```

How can I make my function read the STEPS array to output the correct directory, without duplicates?
This code is not giving me $i inside myfunc.
Also, using myfunc in very important in my case, as I cannot execute the correct code inside parallel without it. So parallel -j 2 myfunc must be preserved

Comment: I don't have `parallel` installed, but isn't what you want just `parallel -j 2 myfunc /home/{}/*vcf ::: 13 13.5` ?